# Nativescript: Black space instead photo thumbnails

Tags: javascript, image, base64, nativescript

Please help, I'm doing a thumbnail of the photos taken with the camera and encode it in base64.

**Javascript:**

```
  class Entry {

  get thumbnail() {
        return (this._thumbnail || null);
  }

  set thumbnail(value) {
        let scaledImage = false;
        if (value) {
            if (value.android) {
                const aspectSafeSize = common.getAspectSafeDimensions(value.width, value.height, config.thumbWidth, config.thumbHeight);
                scaledImage = android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(value.android, aspectSafeSize.width, aspectSafeSize.height, true);
            }
            if (value.ios) {
                const cgSize = CGSizeMake(config.thumbWidth, config.thumbHeight);
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cgSize, false, 0.0);
                value.ios.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, config.thumbWidth, config.thumbHeight));
                scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            }
        }
        if (scaledImage) {
            const scaledImageSource = new ImageSourceModule.ImageSource();
            scaledImageSource.setNativeSource(scaledImage);
            const t = 'data:image/png;base64,' + scaledImageSource.toBase64String('png',100);
            this._thumbnail = t;
        }
    }
}
```

**In XML:**

```
<Image top="0" left="0" src="{{ thumbnail }}" stretch="aspectFill" visibility="{{ thumbnail ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"/>
```

But only displays black space:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmpwW.png).
Moreover, if the encoded data to get and try to decode them, we get a normal picture

Comment: Check if somewhere in your css isn't set css `color` to black if you are on 2.3.0 as there is bug which cause to images to take color from css as inheritance

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have CSS property color set for **any** parent element : 
[this is documented bug](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2733) in NativeScript 2.3.0 and is scheduled for fixing with the next release (2.4.0). If you want to use the next release at this very moment you can do it with this steps:

```
tns plugin remove tns-core-modules
tns plugin add tns-core-modules@next
```

Now you will have the latest modules where the fix is already applied.

Comment: Thank you so much!